# APIM 4.1 Publish and Try out

Tags: wso2-api-manager

im new with APIM 4.1 product. im trying for try_out my project on APIM. but when i put my request and send request request to backend. i got error details :
CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

when i try with integration studio 8.1 with micro service server 4.1 hit local endpoint API i make. i always get http 400 bad status

my project code for this :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/sample2" name="Sample2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request send to endpoint" level="custom">
                <property name="Request Log" value="** Send Request To Endpoint **"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="Test1"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log description="Response back from endpoint" level="custom">
                <property name="Response Log" value="** Response Back From Endpoint **"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>`

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="Test1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="post" uri-template="http://apiceupfdev01.ptap.co.id:31065">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </http>
</endpoint>
```

maybe anyone can helping me with this case.

i expecting get response from backend endpoint i hit

Answer (score 0):

I tried your project on a 4.1.0 pack with an HTTP URL for the endpoint.It worked with a 200 for API invocation call.

If you are getting CORS-related errors, did you try to create the API from the publisher and disable CORS from the runtime configurations[1]? (It is disabled by default for the new APIs that are created from the publisher portal)

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/advanced-topics/enabling-cors-for-apis/#enabling-cors-globally

Comment: i was disable CORS at runtime configuration.. but when i try again send request POST to API at web server and try hit endpoint. still have problem with same. i check deployment.toml. and check any stuff. still same issue